# Magento error in system log

Tags: magento-1.9, error, php-7

I need a little help please.
Last days I am having this error in my magento 1.9.3.8 system log:
`ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Themeframework/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/wpaper/public_html/app/code/local:/home/wpaper/public_html/app/code/community:/home/wpaper/public_html/app/code/core:/home/wpaper/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/php')  in /home/wpaper/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94`

Can anyone help?

Comment: May be for Magento version 1.9 the phhp version should php-5.x not php-7.x

Comment: We have installed inchoophp7. So it runs with php7 now without any problem. This exception appeared after php7. We run php7 about 5 months now and the exception appeared 5-6 days ago.

Comment: it seems Magento wants to include Observer.php form any module but it is not available. Please find " Themeframework" module in your local/community folder and check "Observer.php" exist.

Comment: Have you installed any third party theme?

Comment: Yes.I have installed third party theme but not now.....two years ago....the error appeared now.